# Unable to run example mysqlsh report from 8.0 reference manual

Tags: mysql, report, mysql-shell

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-reporting-create-example.html

```
MySQL [127.0.0.1 ssl] JS> \show
Available reports: query, sessions, thread, threads.
MySQL [127.0.0.1 ssl] JS>
MySQL [127.0.0.1 ssl] JS> \show sessions
reports.sessions: User-defined function threw an exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "init.py", line 2, in sessions
    sys = session.get_schema('sys')
AttributeError: unknown attribute: get_schema
```

> Connection is via MySQL Router.
> mysqlsh -h 127.0.0.1 --user=mysqluser -P 6447

Answer (score 0):

The connection need to be using MySQL X protocol.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).